# OSX : Script to get foremost window details keeps on giving detail of the minimized window

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to get active window details ( app name, process id and window title ) of the foremost window through the applescript given below :

```
global windowTitle,browserTabUrl,appName,appID

set windowTitle to ""
set currentTabTitle to ""

tell application "System Events"

  set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true
  set appName to name of frontApp
  set x to first process whose its frontmost is true
  set appID to unix id of x

  tell process appName
    try
       tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
           set windowTitle to value of attribute "AXTitle"
       end tell
    end try    
  end tell

end tell

return {windowTitle,appName,appID}
```

The script works great ( returns correct app name and window title ) apart  from just one issue wherein **when i minimise the currently focussed active window, then also it keeps giving the details the minimised window.**

For eg: Say I open **Chrome browser** then the script gives me output

```
Active Window Details :  Google Chrome, 829
```

**But when i minimize the chrome browser and some other window ( say skype )** is shown in the background then

Then also the script gives me output

```
 Active Window Details :  Google Chrome, 829
```

**Query : Is there any way by which we can get correct foremost window even after the active window is minimised ??**

**Other Details:**

- I am trying to run this script from nodejs. Code for which is shown [here](https://gist.github.com/bhavyaw/cc327acb3ac8557b2a56c7077461a1ec)
- I am running this script repeatedly in a interval of 500ms.
- I really don't have much experience with applescript

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Also, please let me know if you need any further information regarding the same.

Comment: When you say "after the active window is minimized", which window is then showing?

Comment: @l'L'l ... Suppose there are three windows open in the desktop i.e chrome, skype and atom Editor. Chrome window having the focus. When the chrome window is minimised the skype window is being shown. Will a image be more helpful here ?

Comment: If you look in the left top menu bar (next to the apple menu) is Skype the app name that is shown when the script comes back with Chrome as the frontmost app?

Comment: @l'L'l. No. Its showing chrome only. And i think this is the root cause of problem, but why is it showing chrome when the chrome window has been minimised. Also, is there any way around to get the top most visible window i.e Skype window in this case.

Comment: This is happening because Chrome is actually still active, not Skype. When you simply minimize an app it doesn't make it active (or frontmost) — you actually have to click in it's window to make it the frontmost. You'll probably also want to put an error handler for "windowTitle" in your script, since the title will come back as "not defined" when trying to get it from a minimized app.

Comment: @l'L'l. I guess then what i want want to get is the topmost visible window and not the active window.  Can you please help me with a code sample if possible ? I'll definitely grant the bounty if it works. Asking because its kinda urgent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123161/discussion-between-bhavya-w-and-lll).